# PyQt4 application on Windows is crashing on exit

Tags: python, crash, pyqt4

I am writting a desktop application with PyQt4 and all of the sudden it started to crash on exit.

I reviewed all of my code to make sure I wasn't doing anything funny to make it crash and I don't think there's anything wrong with the code.

I have seen some complaints about this before but it was related to a previous version and people advised to upgrade PyQt4 to the latest version and so I did, but that didn't help with the crashing problem.

So I ask, is there anything that can lead to this behavior with PyQt4, do I need to do some kind on termination procedure to cleanup Qt or anything else I am missing?

Comment: Nobody can answer this without knowing what's in your program.

Comment: At lease, you should should some of your code that may lead to crash. No one can answer your question without any clue.

Comment: There's nothing special on my code. If you just load a .ui with notebook tabs and tableviews on each tab in it and run that, the application is likely to crash on exit. Seems like some problem when releasing memory on Qt cleanup.

Comment: I have also seen exit-related crashes and often they appear to be PyQt bugs. I suspect the only way you'll find out is with a debugger (like gdb, not a python debugger)

Comment: I have also seen pyqt crash on exit. When debugging with gdb, it appears the crash is somewhere in tkinter (bizarre, since I don't use tkinter). It generally hasn't caused problems, though, so I usually just ignore it.

Comment: For me what seem to solve it was to call 
`QtGui.QApplication.instance().aboutToQuit()` in my `closeEvent()` function. I find it super weird that it works, but it does. I also can't explain why calling a signal object would do any good. All I know is that it stopped crashing the minute I've done this (and goes back as soon as I remove it)

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem with a simple hello world application (QDialog with 20 labels). Weirdly the problem disappears with 10 labels.

I solved by forcing exit as follows:

```
def closeEvent(self, event):
    exit()
```

This happens on Windows with PyQt v4.10.3 for Python v2.7 (x32) on VirtualBox.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me! I'm using PyQt 4.11 x86 and I stuck with the same problem, QDialog starts to crashing when window closing.

Answer (score 5):

A debugger will only tell us what we already know: The application crashes on exit.

You probably need to set an active window which, when closed, will result in deterministic garbage collection and a clean application exit. There are more proper ways to do this, but the simpl;e example below should require minimum code changes, and is based on a dialog application that I wrote and works fine.

```
#The application
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

#The main window
MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
app.setActiveWindow(MainWindow) #<---- This is what's probably missing

#the ui
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)

#start the application's exec loop, return the exit code to the OS
exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This perfectly fixed the issue I was also having with PyQt 4.11.4, many thanks!