# PyQt window freezing upon exit

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a very simple PyQt window with a single close button in it. It runs fine until i press close button to exit the program. The PyQt window will just stop responding after i clicked on close button. This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore

class Myclass(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.setGeometry(300,300,250,150)
        self.setWindowTitle('My test')

        quitbtn = QtGui.QPushButton('Close',self)
        quitbtn.setGeometry(10,10,60,35)

        self.connect(quitbtn,QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),
                     QtGui.qApp,QtCore.SLOT('quit()'))

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
myobj = Myclass()
myobj.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I deduced that since it only happen when i click on the close button, there is something wrong with my signal & slot code for close button.But i have no idea what went wrong. Can anyone help me with this? Sorry for the very basic question as i've just started learning PyQt today.

EDIT:
I am using python 2.7.2 and pyqt4

Comment: Are you sure? It runs perfect on my system. What version of python/pyqt are you using?

Comment: Try `QApplication.quit()`...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506781/pyqt4-application-on-windows-is-crashing-on-exit